# How to avoid multiple ifs inside a form?

Tags: java, android

I think this counts for any other language as well, but I'm using Java for Android in this example here. I'm trying to validate a form, but it has multiple inputs.

```
if( !anuncio.getEstado().isEmpty() ){
                if( !anuncio.getCategoria().isEmpty() ){
                    if( !anuncio.getTitulo().isEmpty() ){
                        if( !valor.isEmpty() && !valor.equals("0") ){
                            if( !anuncio.getTelefone().isEmpty()  ){
                                if( !anuncio.getDescricao().isEmpty() ){

                                    saveForm();

                                }else {
                                    showErro("please fill the entire form");
                                }
                            }else {
                                showErro("please fill the entire form");
                            }
                        }else {
                            showErro("please fill the entire form");
                        }
                    }else {
                        showErro("please fill the entire form");
                    }
                }else {
                    showErro("please fill the entire form");
                }
            }else {
                showErro("please fill the entire form");
            }
```

Is there any way or method to simplify this? Because let's say if it were 10 inputs, it would be a horrible code doing 10 ifs, you know? How do I simplify this?

Comment: Use an enum to model your complex state instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this would suffice:

```
if( !anuncio.getEstado().isEmpty() 
    && !anuncio.getCategoria().isEmpty() 
    && !anuncio.getTitulo().isEmpty() 
    && !valor.isEmpty() && !valor.equals("0") 
    && !anuncio.getTelefone().isEmpty() 
    && !anuncio.getDescricao().isEmpty() ) {
    safeForm();
} else {
    showErro("please fill the entire form");
}
```

For more complex code you may i.e. want to count errors and show messages later if `count > 0` etc.

PS also I believe you wanted to write "showError" not "showErro"

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way to write it:

```
    if(!containsEmptyText(anuncio.getEstado(), anuncio.getCategoria(), anuncio.getTitulo(),
        valor, anuncio.getTelefone(), anuncio.getDescricao()) && !valor.equals("0") ){
            saveForm();
    }else
        showErro("please fill the entire form");
```

```
private static boolean containsEmptyText(String... textArray){
    for(String text : textArray)
        if(text.isEmpty())
            return true;

    return false;
}
```